# C# httpwebrequest does not send client certificate

Tags: api, https, request

I try to send request with client certificate to payment gate API. If it goes from browser, it works correct. But help desk says me that their server don't recieve certificate when i make requests from my code below:

```
string host = "https://api.gateway/ping";
            string certName = "cert/cert.p12";

            string password = "certpass";

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
          //  request.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("cert/cert.pfx", "pass"));
            X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            certificates.Import(certName, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet|X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
            request.ClientCertificates = certificates;
            request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
            SetBasicAuthHeader(request, "user", "pass");
            request.UserAgent = "This is request from C# code";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been solved with changing certificate issuing. Simply don't use md5WithRSAEncryption on creating certificate, .NET (from 3.5 to .NET Core) will ignore attaching such certificates.